# Cannot load any css and js file after build when using vue-cli and webpack?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using koa2 as backend and koa-swig to render my page. Here is the structure:
[image]

Inside dist file, there are index.html and static. All css, js, and images are in there. And here is the error:
[image]

Here is the build setting in `config/index.js` of webpack:

```
build: {
   env: require('./prod.env'),
   index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
   assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
   assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
   assetsPublicPath: '/',
   productionSourceMap: true,
   productionGzip: false,
   productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
   bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

After you build the Vue.js app, your output files will be available in `dist/` folder.

From this point onwards, your webpack build config does not matter. What matters is how your server handles the requests.

The contents of `dist` folder will have the following:

1. `index.html` file
2. `static` folder

I assume you would copy the above files to your server for end-to-end testing.

Your `index.html` links to files in your static folder using plain `<script>` or `<link>` tags. After your browser fetches the `index.html`, it will start requesting all the other files like `app.xyz.js`, `vendor.xyz.js`, etc. You either need to ensure that these static files are accessible in their default paths, or change path as explained in the below example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/app.xyz.js"></script>
```

may need to be changed to

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static_files/scripts/app.xyz.js"></script>
```

You need to look at server logs to see why the requests are not getting served. Once you fix the server side errors, then your Vue app will work normally in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the config `assetsPublicPath: '/'`  to  `assetsPublicPath: '../dist'`, it works for me.

Comment: the option is now called `publicPath: ''`